# Ubuntu dig on windows

Tags: windows, dns

Hello I am using the following command on Ubuntu:

```
dig google.com @localhost -p 4000
```

I need a corresponding command on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the digtool comes along with bind for windows. Use the below url to download bind - https://www.isc.org/downloads/
Once installed, dig will work on windows.

You can follow the instructions from this blog - http://nil.uniza.sk/linux-howto/how-install-dig-dns-tool-windows-10